# How to join multiple tables using GORM without Preload

Tags: go, go-gorm

I currently have 3 tables with relation between them through GORM. I'm looking to query the sellers with all informations about the relation.
Here's my entities:

```golang
type ShopType struct {
    ID      uint       `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    Name    string     `json:"name" xml:"name" form:"name" query:"name"
}

type Shop struct {
    ID             uint       `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    Name           string     `json:"name" xml:"name" form:"name" query:"name"
    ShopType       ShopType   `gorm:"ShopTypeID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:RESTRICT;" json:"-"`
}


type Seller struct {
    ID           uint       `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    Firstname    string     `json:"firstname" xml:"firstname" form:"firstname" query:"firstname"
    Lastname     string     `json:"lastname" xml:"lastname" form:"lastname" query:"lastname"
    Shop         Shop       `gorm:"foreignKey:ShopID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:RESTRICT;" json:"-"`
}
```

It's not possible to use `Joins` instead of `Preload` like :

```
db.Model(&models.Seller{}).Joins("Shop").Joins("Shop.ShopType").Find(&results)
```

?

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

Also I have tried :

```
db.Model(&models.Seller{}).Joins("JOIN shops s on s.id = sellers.shop_id").Joins("JOIN shop_types st on st.id = s.shop_type_id")
```

It's work but it didn't fill the props of the Shop and ShopType entities, only the informations about the sellers are filled.

I'm looking to joins my entities using `Joins` instead of `Preload` because I want add some clauses to my query like : `.Where('Shop.ShopType.Name IN (?)')` and that's not possible with the `Preload` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there with the second query, you can combine the `Preload` and `Where` functions with it.

```
var sellers []Seller 
db.Joins("JOIN shops s on s.id = sellers.shop_id").
       Joins("JOIN shop_types st on st.id = s.shop_type_id").
       Preload("Shop.ShopType").
       Where("st.name IN (?)", []string{"Store1", "Store2"}).
       Find(&sellers)
```

Comment: Yes thanks, It's what i did finally, so 2 SQL requests instead of 1 but no choices...